# How to find all (metaplex) nfts by (verified) collection?

Tags: metaplex, nft, fetch, metaplex-js

Is there any way to find mints of all nfts which are verified to be a part of a given collection?

I know I can find all by mint list, owner, or creator. The creator here has other nfts so I could get all from the creator then filter, but it's kinda slow. Any way to directly fetch by collection?

Someone asked this back on the solana forums but there's not much of an answer there. https://forums.solana.com/t/possible-to-query-all-nft-addresses-in-a-specific-collection/3097/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot easily do a `getProgramAccounts()` like one can do for creators. You can still search for all NFTs in a collection when parsing all collection transactions.

It is possible with [metaboss](https://metaboss.rs/collections.html#get-items) where an indexer is used or by parsing the transactions like in this metaplex rust and typescript [examples](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/get-collection).

Comment: @mikemaccana getProgramAccounts